# How to not save the added record when changing windows in oracle forms?

Tags: oracleforms

I am having a problem of identifying the issue and what to look for in Oracle Forms. I made a condition where it won't commit except when saving. But somehow, when adding a record and I change my windows screen from the application, it is saving.

I tried my code in a normal scenario, however, when accessing new screen and going back to my current screen, it is saving. This is the only issue I encountered. Thanks

Comment: "change my windows screen from the application" - what does that mean? Could you post a screenshot (or several screenshots) that illustrate what you're saying?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is a bit unclear.  For example, you said "*I made a condition where it won't commit except when saving*...".  What does this mean? By design, Forms will only commit when "saving".  The only exception is if in your own code you execute a `COMMIT` or `COMMIT_FORM`.

It sounds like you need to look carefully at your own code.

Also, in the future it would be very helpful if you would include the product versions when you post.  This is important because some versions may behave differently in some cases.